# App error if null image URL is loaded in JSON object

Tags: json, swift

I am populating a tableView with objects from a MySQL table via JSON. The source data are introduced by many users in a web site form, and sometimes they don't introduce an image URL into a field.

The downloaded JSON object are shown in the tableView which rows are configured to show text, detail text and image.

If the object doesn't have an image URL, the app error, and I want to show a default image instead, to avoid the crash.

My code:

```
let url:URL = URL(string: "http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?a=Non_Alcoholic")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL)) { (data, resp, error) in
        if (error == nil && data != nil) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
                do {
                    let DuLieu = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                    let Mang = DuLieu.value(forKey: "drinks") as! NSArray

                    for mang in Mang {
                        let dulieu = mang as! NSDictionary

                        let strDrink = dulieu.value(forKey: "strDrink") as! String
                        let strDrinkThumb = dulieu.value(forKey: "strDrinkThumb") as! String //Image (Error loading)
                        let idDrink = dulieu.value(forKey: "idDrink") as! String

                        self.danhmuc.append(DanhMuc(hinhanh: strDrinkThumb, tieude: strDrink, id: idDrink))
                    }
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                } catch {
                    print("Error")
                }
            })
        }
    }.resume()
```

Image - (Error loading) - code:

```
let strDrinkThumb = dulieu.value(forKey: "strDrinkThumb") as! String
```

How to display a default image if the web site user doesn't include an image URL in the web form?

Comment: if it can be null so you should use String?

Comment: Make `strDrinkThumb` optional instead of force-casting it.

Comment: Better to use conditional cast combined with nil coalescing operator `??` and add the default image string after that